# Calling the keyboard delete/backspace action on a button?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

Is there a way to put the keyboard backspace action on the button or will I have to do it custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [Instrumentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation) class to simulate a [Keyevent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) with code.

in `kotlin`

```
val instrumentation = Instrumentation()
instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
```

I just test it and worked on my emulator (API 29)

**Notice:** [`Instrumentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation) can not be called in `main-thread`

---

so you may do this below

in `Kotlin`

```
thread
{
    Instrumentation()
    instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
{
```

in `Java`

```
new Thread()
{
    ..
    new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
    ..
}.start();
```

---

*KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL* = *BackSpace*

*KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL* = *Delete*

---

**Update example**

let me show you a snippet

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Instrumentation instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
                    instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2S7p.jpg)

Comment: But what do I call it in edittext (Java / Android)?

Comment: you can focus to a `EditText`, and then try to click the `Button`, you will find something changed.

Comment: I still did not get it :/

Comment: I looked at the example and it's exactly what I want but I still don't know how to do :/

Comment: I edit to provide a snippet, you only need to do is `focus on the view` what you want to handle, and then send the `KeyEvent`.